In Laravel, how can I get the validation errors
I am getting the web method just thrown out, and rest of the code after the line (see code below) doesn't run. With this code, I cannot seem to get where the error is, even though I can see that the Laravel has issues with the email being unique. I only have handful of users, and all of them have different emails. I can see that in the DB. This is the code, in any case:
$validatedData = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'nullable|min:6',
            'name' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'about_me' => 'nullable|string|max:300',
        ]);

if I omit the part |unique:users  the code runs fine i.e. it gets past the $validatedData=.... line. Why is Laravel making this mistake? The email is indeed unique, I see it clearly in the DB for the 10 or so users that I have. I want to see what errors is Laravel catching, and also, because I assume it is catching the email error, the email being not unique (which is not true, the email is unique), why is he doing this?

What do you mean web method just thrown out? Is it throwing an exception? In your blade file, you can get the errors using the $errors variable

Is this happening when you are updating the record? If yes then while updating the record you will have to ignore the current user's ID from the unique check.
$validatedData = $request->validate([
                    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
                    'password' => 'nullable|min:6',
                    'name' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
                    'about_me' => 'nullable|string|max:300',
                ]);

OR
$validatedData = $request->validate([
                    'email' => ['required','email',Rule::unique('users')->ignore($id)],
                    'password' => 'nullable|min:6',
                    'name' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
                    'about_me' => 'nullable|string|max:300',
                ]);

Please check validation

this is the detail that I wasn't aware of. The id has to be excluded during the update. Thanks!
